# How to DefultView Rowfilter add new

Tags: c#, datatable

```
private void categoryCheckedListBox_ItemCheck(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ItemCheckEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.State==CheckState.Checked)
            {
                string categoryName = categoryCheckedListBox.Items[e.Index].Value.ToString();
                (productListGV.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Kata2 LIKE '%{0}%' AND Kata1 LIKE '%{1}%'", categoryName,Cins);

            }
            else
            {
                (productListGV.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = null;
            }

        }
```

Hello Category always sounds different and dynamic. What I want is to add it to the filter for each selected checkbox value. CategoryName can have different value.

I did DefaultView.RowFilter+=.... but is error.

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over `categoryCheckedListBox.Items`, compose your `string.Format` `String` based on the iterations and then pass to the `string.Format`s `Object` an array with the checked corresponding strings.

Example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
// Lacking actual data, I made an assumption that Kata concatenated with the key will correspond to the actual column
(productListGV.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Join(" AND ", new[] { "a", "b", "c" }.Select((val, key) => $"Kata{key} LIKE '%{val}%'" ));
```

Or:

```cs
using System;
string[] a = new[] { "a", "b", "c" };
string s = String.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) s+= $"Kata{i} LIKE '%{a[i]}%'";
(productListGV.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format(s, a);
```

I believe you get the picture.